# How can I verify if two char * are equal in Google Mock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Let's say I have a Mock like this:

```
class MockSocket : public Socket
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(Write, bool(Packet *p));
};
```

And I want to test if the Write method is called with an object that satisfies the following conditions:

- 1) when I call the get_QL() function on this object I receive 0 as a
  return value
- 2) when I call get_MAC() function I receive a uint8_t*
  that I know has length 6, but no string terminator.

How can I write the second condition in GMock?
I tried something like this but the second property is not working correctly.

```
EXPECT_CALL(ms, Write(AllOf(Property(&ESMCPacket::get_QL, 0), Property(&ESMCPacket::get_MAC, (mmac_source1))))).Times(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether gMock has the memory matcher like you need but it's trivial to write a custom one:

```
MATCHER_P2(MatchesMemory, data, size, "") {
  return memcmp(arg, data, size) == 0;
}

EXPECT_CALL(
    ms,
    Write(AllOf(Property(&ESMCPacket::get_QL, 0),
                Property(&ESMCPacket::get_MAC, MatchesMemory("abc\0ef", 6))))
    .Times(1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'e already found the solution and it's by writing my own matcher too :)